# Docker stats memory anomaly

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, ram

Thanks for taking the time to read my problem is the following, my **auto-escalation policies are associated with a docker container**, if the container requires autoscale memonia. ***In the container the processes (top) our one less load to "docker stats id"***. There are times when the RAM of the container becomes saturated because the dentry is not live (page cache)

**docker stats does not show the actual RAM consumption that the container uses:**

**docker stats bf257938fa2d** **66.54MiB**

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                    CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %               NET I/O             
bf257938fa2d        ce88cfdda8f09bc08101   0.00%               66.54MiB / 512MiB   13.00%              1.44MB / 1.26MB     40.3MB / 0B         0
```

**docker exec -it bf257938fa2d top **

```
top - 23:24:02 up 53 min,  0 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.21, 0.21
Tasks:   6 total,   1 running,   5 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  3.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.6%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  15660100k total,  1989516k used, 13670584k free,    95920k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  1167184k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
    1 root      20   0 11604 2468 2284 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 bash               
    6 root      20   0  309m  12m 7036 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.09 php-fpm            
    7 root      20   0 59292 7100 6052 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nginx              
    8 nginx     20   0 59728 4824 3352 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 nginx              
    9 nginx     20   0 59728 4800 3328 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 nginx              
   70 root      20   0 15188 2040 1832 R  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 top
```

In what way could solve, that RAM consumption is equal in the container (top) and outside the container (docker stats).

Thank you

Comment: Which numbers from `top` do you expect to match with the `stats` output?

Comment: When I'm inside the container I use the top command and from the host I use the docker stats command, the use of RAM does not match

Comment: In top, are you looking at the VIRT, RES, or SHR columns in top for calculating your memory? Have you checked the units for each?

Comment: Check top command (VIRT, RES or SHR) only "echo 3> /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches" shows true RAM